# WIFI - DNS works but internet does not

Tags: wifi, dns

I am trying to connect my raspberry to WPA2-Personal network. Raspberry connects to the WIFI and is assigned IP but I am not able to use the internet (DNS seems to work tho):

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ping www.sdnojdsdooxgnfija.com
ping: unknown host www.sdnojdsdooxgnfija.com
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.209.68) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.55.21 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

`ifconfig -a` gives:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b4:ee:b4:87:41:c8  
          inet addr:192.168.1.116  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          ...
```

/etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto wlan0
iface lo inet loopback
face eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Comment: do you have any firewall settings enabled on your router. Such as allow only certain Mac address or something

Comment: No, but I will check if it works with another router. I am connected to the PI via ethernet cable and it has static IP - 169.254.55.21. Maybe this is the issue?

Comment: The raspberry prefers ethernet over WiFi, meaning that it will try to connect via the ethernet if available. Please disconnect from ethernet and connect to the PI wirelessly

Comment: Okay, managed to connect wirelessly but still no internet ( again DNS works)

Comment: Have you rebooted the PI once disconnected the ethernet (I can't seem to remember the service that takes care of networking). If still no luck can you also post your interfaces file content to see if that's the issue

Comment: Thank you for your time. After reboot still does not work. I will update my question to include the file

Comment: And one more thing that may be relevant: I edited boot/cmdline.txt file and added ip=169.254.55.21

Comment: Can you undo that as well. Also if there isn't much you have done on the PI, you might as well reinstall  the OS.

Comment: If you do not know how to set a static IP using the interfaces file do let me know. I'll type it out in the answers

Comment: Okay I think I will try removing that part and if it does not work I will reinstall the OS. Thank you for your help!

Comment: For editing Lan settings use interfaces file. For editing WiFi settings go to the wpa_supplicant file

Comment: Did not have to! This cmdline.txt thing was the issue! THANK YOU!

Comment: Awesome, please mark the question as  answered to reduce the number of unanswered questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question has been answered in the comments itself

OP had added **ip=169.254.55.21** to **boot/cmdline.txt**, removing this fixed the problem